# Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined at window.onload with SwaggerUI on typescript

Tags: typescript, express, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to add Swagger documentation to my Express project (TypeScript) using the following definition in `app.ts`:

```js
...
import swaggerJsDoc from 'swagger-jsdoc'
import  swaggerUi from 'swagger-ui-express'

...

const swaggerDefinition ={
    openapi:'3.0.0',
    info:{
        title:'Swagger Test API',
        version:'1.0.0',
    }

}
const options={
    swaggerDefinition,
    apis:['./src/api/routes/*.ts'],
    server:['http://localhost:3000']
}
const swaggerSpec = swaggerJsDoc(options)

app.use('/swagger',swaggerUi.serve,swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec))
```

I have the bundles `swagger-jsdoc` and 'swagger-ui-express' installed.

On starting the development server, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at swagger-ui-bundle.js:3:1)
swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js:3 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js:3:1)
Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined
    at window.onload
```

Is there a way to resolve this, or is this an existing issue in swagger

Comment: Do you use Vercel (`vercel dev`)?